# Is BEVM valid or we can use modifier alone?

Tags: html, css, bem

[Chainable BEM modifiers](https://webuild.envato.com/blog/chainable-bem-modifiers/)

And I want to apply this idea to my next project but when I get the check on getbem.com, It says is bad when use modifier alone

```html
Good

<div class="block block--mod">...</div>
 <div class="block block--size-big
  block--shadow-yes">...</div>

Bad

<div class="block--mod">...</div>
```

meanwhile, in BEVM idea, we can use modifier alone in an element.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

BEM is against modifiers without block class itself. They are to modify something existing.

There can be quite a lot of different modifiers on a block at the same time (we need to avoid repetition of basic things in each modifier) and they can be added or removed in runtime. So there should always be the entity (block or element) to witch modifiers can be added or from which they can be removed.

For more info please refer to https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#how-to-make-global-modifiers-for-blocks